# How to convert txt.knowtator.xml file to .ann?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, annotations, brat

I have an annotated dataset in `txt.knowtator.xml` format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<annotations textSource="file.txt">
    <annotation>
        <mention id="EHOST_Instance_93" />
        <annotator id="01">Unknown</annotator>
        <span start="127" end="237" />
        <spannedText>Omeprazole</spannedText>
        <creationDate>Wed Mar 11 09:52:01 GMT 2010</creationDate>
    </annotation>
    <classMention id="EHOST_Instance_93">
        <mentionClass id="Treatment">Omeprazole</mentionClass>
    </classMention>
    <annotation>
        <mention id="EHOST_Instance_94" />
        <annotator id="01">Unkown</annotator>
        <span start="600" end="612" />
        <spannedText>Tegretol</spannedText>
        <creationDate>Wed Mar 11 09:55:11 GMT 2010</creationDate>
    </annotation>
    <classMention id="EHOST_Instance_94">
        <mentionClass id="Treatment">Tegretol</mentionClass>
</annotations>
```

I need to get it into [standoff BRAT format](https://brat.nlplab.org/standoff.html) (`.ann`), such as:

```
T1    Treatment 127 137    Omeprazole
T2    Treatment 600 612    Tegretol
```

Is there any available tool for converting/parsing?

Comment: Start by uploading a **valid** xml. Where does `T1` comes from? What is the expected output? We dont know what is `.ann`

Comment: Edited. T1 indicates an entity in BRAT standoff. The output is the last code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<annotations textSource="file.txt">
    <annotation>
        <mention id="EHOST_Instance_93" />
        <annotator id="01">Unknown</annotator>
        <span start="127" end="237" />
        <spannedText>Omeprazole</spannedText>
        <creationDate>Wed Mar 11 09:52:01 GMT 2010</creationDate>
    </annotation>
    <classMention id="EHOST_Instance_93">
        <mentionClass id="Treatment">Omeprazole</mentionClass>
    </classMention>
</annotations>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(f'T1    Treatment {root.find(".//span").attrib["start"]} {root.find(".//span").attrib["end"]} {root.find(".//spannedText").text}')
```

output

```
T1    Treatment 127 237 Omeprazole
```

Comment: Thank you, that works: "Treatment" token can be collected with root.find(".//mentionSlot").attrib["id"]. However it only works for the first annotation. I have edited my question

Comment: @torakxkz I have answered your question as you posted it. Please accept the answer. If you have a new question - create a new post.